# Neo4j goes off on CentoOS server

Tags: neo4j, centos, cypher, graph-databases

My neo4j stops by itself after some time on my Godaddy CentOS server. I have to run `neo4j start` before it come up again.

Comment: Is there something in the `debug.log` log file of Neo4j ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if godaddy server go to sleep mode after some inactivity time but you could try to enable the service to start it when the server spin up again.

`systemctl enable neo4j`

this command might need sudo permission